# Twitter data harvesting

Tags: apache-spark, twitter, raspberry-pi, apache-kafka

For my project, I need to harvest data from Twitter.

I am currently facing two design choices:

1. What is the best software architecture? I read that spark has Twitter support but I am not familiar with Scala. On the other hand, Apache Spark seems a good option, but then I'm not sure on how to save data to a common sink
2. I have some budget constraints. I surely need one server to do the sink and the processing. However, for the data harvesting, I don't know if several VM/containers offer a better performance / cost ratio than a bunch of Raspberry PI running Kafka producers.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at Confluent platform and especially Kafka Connect [1].

There is a Twitter connector out of the box. All the twitter data will be streamed to Kafka.

[1] https://www.confluent.io/blog/using-ksql-to-analyse-query-and-transform-data-in-kafka

Comment: Twitter connector isn't included out of the box. Needs to be compiled separately

Comment: As cricket_007 says, the Twitter connector has to be [downloaded separately](https://github.com/jcustenborder/kafka-connect-twitter). You can see details of its usage in [this article](https://www.confluent.io/blog/using-ksql-to-analyse-query-and-transform-data-in-kafka).

Answer (score 1):

Agree with @leshkin that Kafka Connect is the most natural fit. However, the Twitter connector ([available on github here](https://github.com/jcustenborder/kafka-connect-twitter)) does not require Confluent Platform, simply Kafka Connect which is a standard part of the Apache Kafka distribution. https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#connect

If you choose, you can run Kafka connect workers in distributed mode to divide the load across several VMs/containers/boxes and these don't have to be the same boxes you run your kafka brokers (they only need some relevant libs from kafka and the libs for the connector and Java of course)

Comment: Thanks! This is interesting. I understand that the producer will be I/O (net) intensive, so easily containerizable.